# Git repository without refs directory but with packed-refs file is invalid

Tags: git, bundler

Somehow, I got into a state where I had some git repos that didn't have a `refs` directory, but did have a `packed-refs` file. When trying to use those repos, git would immediately error out with:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

All I had to do was make an empty `refs` directory, and git would work, and even report all the information about branches stored in the `packed-refs` files.

Should a git repo without a `refs` directory, but with a `packed-refs` file really be considered invalid? How did my repos even get into this situation?

These repos were ones used by `bundler`. For example, they were at:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/resque-841a12220f681ab6c7edba71d186ddfb64ee193f
```

Removing those directories, or creating the empty `refs` dirs under them did the trick. It's still just confusing why this would happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unpack packed-refs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333255/how-to-unpack-packed-refs)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I don't really care about unpacking them. I can just create the empty refs directory and everything works. I just want to know if it's really correct to interpret a git repo without a refs dir, but *with* a valid packed-refs file as invalid. And I'm curious as to how `bundler` and I even got into this situation since I don't ever directly interact with these repos.

Comment: GIt's check to see if a directory is a valid repository consists of inspecting to see if it has: a valid `HEAD`, a `refs/`, and an `objects/` (or `$GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY`). So, yes, if the `refs/` directory is missing, Git will decide that that's not a repository.  See [is_git_directory](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a/setup.c#L309-L347). (I have no idea how yours got the way it did.)

Comment: It happened because Git doesn't expect to ever produce a repo that looks like yours so it it doesn't recognize yours. Whatever produced it, that's a bug, nothing confusing about it. I'm betting that 3rd-party repo wrangler did it, or somebody experimenting and getting surprised.

Comment: @torek. Yeah that does seem to be the literal reason why git fails early. But I'm also wondering why... if a line entry in `packed-refs` is considered the same as a file under the `refs` dir, maybe it would be more correct for the check to be for `refs` or `packed-refs`. And how did I even get into this situation since I'm not manually going into these paths and deleting directories, and I assume bundler is just using plain git commands to interact with these repos.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the problem, but: packed-refs is "new" (at maybe a decade old), as a solution to the fact that some repos fill up with megabytes of tags, which take about 2% of the previous disk space once packed. Probably the `is_git_directory` code predates packed-refs files. I'm still expecting references to become a real database someday.

Comment: Same problem here with some old test repos I inherited. Thanks a million for the hint of adding an empty refs directory!